# AWS Lambda python Resetting dropped connection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I've an AWS Python Lambda which manages resources tags(many calls on the AWS API with boto3) for my infrastructure. The function, executed on my laptop works well and also under Lambda. But when I execute it under Lambda, all my logs(debug or error level) are not send to cloudwatch logs. Instead of I've multiple logs like this:

```
Resetting dropped connection: ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Resetting dropped connection: ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Google said me that it's a problem relative to urlib3 and a too high request frequency against the AWS API.

My question is, how can avoid it in Lambda to retrieve my logs in cloudwatch logs? I search a better solution than put multiple sleep inside my code. Is there a way to do that globally?

Thanks

Comment: How are you sending the logs to CloudWatch? From what I've experienced, you can actually just use the standard `logging` package to log to the console and everything ends up in CloudWatch nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For logging:

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.debug("xxxx")

Comment: Moreover the log seems to be well pushed to cloudwatch because I can see my first log which indicated the start of my lambda but after it, I've only "the dropped connection" logs. It seems that they overwrite my logs.

Comment: Sorry, just so I really understand this: you are not using `urllib3` yourself to ship logs to Cloudwatch? Also, if you set your logger to "INFO" and then use `logger.debug`(), these entries will not show up (in case you were looking for these log messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally it works. Indeed I was too aggressive on the retry process but I need to do each operation ASAP(ex: attach an EBS when it is available). In boto3, there is a cleaner way to wait until a resource become ready, than to put time.sleep(xx) in your code.

The solution is to use a [boto3 waiter](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters)
My advice is to set a custom value for the retry interval because per default it's 15s(too long).

```
waiter.config.delay = 1
waiter.config.max_attempts = 10(as you want for this param)
```

With this parameters you avoid lambda to send logs like this "Resetting dropped connection: ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" and you execute your Lambda in the fastest way.

I'm agree with smdev who said that it's not a good idea to put sleep inside a lambda function(boto3 waiter is a sleep like) but for me it is acceptable when your Lambda function is called only few time. For example when an Autoscaling notification invokes your Lambda. 
If your Lambda is called directly by API Gateway(example) at a moderate or high frequency it's a very bad idea but if it's only 2-3 times per day it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

AWS clodwatch logs will not "overwrite" your own logs. Please **do not sleep in the lambda function** since you will be paying for this as well. Also if the request rate is too high, you will get `RequestLimitExceeded` errors.

There are some ways to avoid this:

1. Check and remove any boto code that is calling the AWS API in a tight loop (for/while)
2. Use iterators, `MaxResults` and pagination in boto code to get a list/collection of items instead of querying for individual ones
3. Use two lambda's with sqs in between ( for cases where there is an async dependency). For example if deleting un-used AMI's - one lambda to identify and deregister AMI's and push related snapshots to sqs. Second lambda to read from sqs and delete snapshots.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I'm agree with you that sleeping inside a Lambda function is not a good way but for example, in my case, I create an EBS volume and attach it to an instance. But before to can attach it, I need to wait until the volume become "available", and so I need to check his status. I need to attach it as soon as possible. How you do you handle this case?

Comment: Humm, I think I can answer my own question, use waiters... But at the same time a waiter just performs automatic retry every X seconds.

Comment: Your case is an asynchronous case (see point 3). I would handle it using a SQS/SNS and two lambda functions. The first lambda would create an EBS volume and send the volume id and the instance id to which it needs to be attached as a message to SQS/SNS. The second lambda would be reading the SQS/SNS and try to attach the volume if it is available if not look for the next message. If there are no messages, it can exit. Choice of SQS/SNS would be dependent on if you like push or pull.

Answer (score -3):

where to put this wait configuration:

```
waiter.config.delay = 1
waiter.config.max_attempts = 10
```

(as you want for this param)